# Reading from serial port in C

Tags: serial-port, arduino, xbee

I'm trying to read from Arduino (who's sending char '4' constantly) with [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee).

I have tried writing from the PC to Arduino, and it works, so the connection is correct.

When I execute de following code, the terminal doesn't show anything and don't finish the program, so it gets stuck on reading.

```
#include <stdio.h>     // Standard input / output functions
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>     // String function definitions
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <errno.h>      // Error number definitions
#include <termios.h>    // POSIX terminal control definitions
#define XBEE "/dev/ttyUSB0"
#define BAUDRATE B9600

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    struct termios tio;
    struct termios stdio;
    struct termios old_stdio;

    int tty_fd = open(XBEE , O_RDWR| O_NOCTTY);

    cfsetospeed(&tio,BAUDRATE);
    cfsetispeed(&tio,BAUDRATE);            // Baudrate is declared above
    tcsetattr(tty_fd,TCSANOW,&tio);
    // for(i;i<5;i++){
    // write(tty_fd,&c,1); //If new data is available on the console, send it to the serial port
    // write(tty_fd,&o,1); //If new data is available on the console, send it to the serial port

    // }
    int n=0;
    char buf = '\0';

    /* Whole response*/

    do
    {
       n = read( tty_fd, &buf, sizeof(char) );
    }
    while( n > 0);

    if (n < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR READING");
    }
       else if (n == 0)
    {
        printf("Read nothing!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Response: %c",buf);
    }
    close(tty_fd);
    tcsetattr(STDOUT_FILENO,TCSANOW,&old_stdio);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How do I solve this?

**UPDATE**

I tried this other code and receive a warning: turning off output flushing and then the terminal froze.

```
#include <stdio.h>      // Standard input / output functions
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>     // String function definitions
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <errno.h>      // Error number definitions
#include <termios.h>    // POSIX terminal control definitions
#define XBEE "/dev/ttyUSB0"
#define BAUDRATE B9600

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    struct termios tio;
    struct termios stdio;
    struct termios old_stdio;
    struct termios options;

    int tty_fd = open(XBEE , O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    cfsetospeed(&tio,BAUDRATE);
    cfsetispeed(&tio,BAUDRATE);            // Baudrate is declared above
    tcsetattr(tty_fd,TCSANOW,&tio);

    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;
    // for(i;i<5;i++){
    // write(tty_fd,&c,1);//if new data is available on the console, send it to serial port
    // write(tty_fd,&o,1);//if new data is available on the console, send it to serial port

    // }
    int n=0;
    char buf = '1';
    int i = 1;
    /* Whole response*/

    while(i==1){
        n = read( tty_fd, &buf, sizeof(char) );

        if (n < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR READING");
        }
           else if (n == 0)
        {
            printf("Read nothing!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Response: %c",buf);
            close(tty_fd);
            break;
        }
    }
    tcsetattr(STDOUT_FILENO,TCSANOW,&old_stdio);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: *"I have tried writing from pc to arduino and it works, so the connection is correct"* -- If that code is similar to what you posted, then it is not working and the connection is not "correct".  You need to check the return code from all syscalls such as **open()** and **tcsetattr()**.  You should study [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html).  You are misusing **tcsetattr()**.  You are using struct termios tio without first initializing it (by calling **tcgetattr()**).

Comment: *"I'm trying to read from arduino (who's sending char '4' constantly)"* -- Besides the incomplete setup of the serial port, your program won't read any characters because the port is probably still in canonical mode, and (you wrote that) the Arduino is not sending any line termination characters.

Comment: @sawdust, you should put those comments in an answer -- they definitely will help with the reported problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to be using C to communicate with XBee modules, you might want to check out this [Open Source XBee Host library](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library).  You could just use the serial driver from it in your code, or take a look at the `xbee_term` sample program as a simple terminal.

Comment: I tried it but is not exactly what i want, although I think that is a awesome API and very useful, i found the solution, it was in the code but i dont know why now works and then no, but its working now, thank you to you all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing data, why are you using printf? You must use the Serial.print() syntax w.r.t the Arduino IDE.

Comment: That code is my pc program, the code in arduino works perfectly